# How to add kotlin class to gradle JavaCompile task

Tags: java, jpa, gradle, spring-boot, kotlin

I use kotlin and java with spring boot to develop my project.
My build tool is gradle, a task is defined as follows:

```
configurations {
  providedRuntime
  jpametamodel
}

dependencies {
    jpametamodel ('org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:4.3.11.Final')
}

task generateMetaModel(type: JavaCompile, group: 'build', description: 'metamodel generate') {

   source = sourceSets.main.java
   classpath = configurations.compile + configurations.jpametamodel
   options.compilerArgs = ["-proc:only"]
   destinationDir = sourceSets.generated.java.srcDirs.iterator().next()

  doFirst {
      delete(sourceSets.generated.java.srcDirs)
  }
}
```

This task works with out kotlin class, but if I add kotlin class, the task cannot work by throw the following errors:

```
Hibernate JPA 2 Static-Metamodel Generator 4.3.11.Final
/.../src/main/java/com/app/web/rest/UserResource.java:18: 
Cannot find .....
import com.app.web.rest.dto.SimpleUser;
                         ^
 Symbol:   Class SimpleUser
 Position: Package com.app.web.rest.dto
```

The SimpleUser is defined in kotlin file:

```
 SimpleUser.kt
 data class SimpleUser(val str:String)
```

Comment: FYI you don't have to generate a meta-model if you don't want to - see [kotlin-jpa-specification-dsl](https://github.com/consoleau/kotlin-jpa-specification-dsl)

Comment: The meta-model is used in my other java code.

Answer (score 0):

The Hibernate meta-model generator is implemented as a JSR 269 annotation processor. When using Kotlin, you'll need to enable annotation processing explicitly by [applying the kapt compiler plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html). When you do that, you'll find that the meta-model gets generated for Kotlin entities.